# Winforms with OnKeyDown and additional Controls

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a Windows.Form where I override the `OnKeyDown`

```
override protected void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e) {
    // do things on specific key presses
}
```

This works all fine, until I add my Button

```
class MyWinForm : Form {
    static System.Windows.Forms.Timer Timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
    static EventHandler EveryTick;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Button button1;

    public MyWinForm() {
         Width = 300;
         Height = 300;
         Text = "MyWinForm";
         this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
         this.button1.Text = "Start";
         this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100,50);
         this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(10, Height -80);
         this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(ButtonClick);
         this.Controls.Add(this.button1);
    }
    static void Main() {
         // Some more stuff is happening here
         Application.Run(new MyWinForm());
    }
```

As soon as I add `this.Controls.Add(this.button1);` my OnKeyDown doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Is the button the sole control on the form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All keyboard events always go to the control that has the focus. In a form without any control, it's the form itself that receives all keyboard events, unless you set the property [KeyPreview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview(v=vs.110).aspx) to `true`.

Before adding the button, the event on the form is the only candidate to handle the event, but after adding the button, by default, it becomes the receiver of all events. Setting `KeyPreview` to `true` restores the form as the receiver of all keyboard events.